# Bash newline in string grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

```
$ cat ansible/file | grep "Other users"
Other users
```

How can i add a new string on a new line after my grep as above?

```
$ cat ansible/file | grep "Other users"
Other users
NewString  # New line with new string appended to file
```

Comment: use this command :
cat ansible/file | grep "Other users" | | awk '{print $0 "\nNewString"}'

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new/ on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should use awk:

```
awk '{print} /Other users/{print "New Line"}' file
```

The above will work robustly and efficiently with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box and will be trivial to enhance/maintain if/when your requirements change later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to find the string you're looking for, and replace it with itself + the new line:

```
sed "s/Other users/Other users\nNew Line/g"
```

We're replacing "Other users" with "Other users\nNew String" (which is the string itself, and a new line appended to it with the content you want to insert).

Comment: suggestions and observations: 1) use single quotes unless double are needed 2) in case there are other characters in the matching line, you'll need to cover that 3) `\n` is not portable 4) sed has `a` command for this use case